# Django admin doesn't serve media correctly but view does

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

So I have a view that looks like this that I found on stack overflow. It works great. It gives me my .zip file and I am happy as a clam. Only one problem. When i log in to the admin and try to download the same file, the download starts and chokes at 0.0 mb with a network error. How do I put the logic below behind my admin site without explicitly pointing the url for my FileField to this view?

```
def script_download(request, script_id):
    scripts = Script.objects.get(id=script_id)
    fsock = open(str(scripts.zipfile),'r')
    response = HttpResponse(fsock, content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s  "% str(scripts.zipfile)
    return response
```

The admin docs aren't helping me. Can you?

Comment: Don't you think it's a good idea to post the full error dump

Comment: I don't have an error dump. The Apache server sends a HTTP 200, and it just times out in browser.